# Dynamically give array bounds to ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS v1.3.15.

I've 2 variables namely `currentYear` and `leastSearchYear` in my controller. I can build entire year list in a variable & return it but I don't need that list in my controller as its just for selecting a single value.

I'm trying this:

Controller-

```
$scope.leastSearchYear = 1950; // this will come from a ws-call later
$scope.currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
```

Webpage-

```
<select ng-model="yearFrom">
    <option ng-repeat="year in currentYear .. leastSearchYear" value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
</select>
```

I've also tried this:

```
ng-repeat="year in {{currentYear}} .. {{leastSearchYear}}"
```

Even tried this:

```
ng-repeat="year in [currentYear .. leastSearchYear]"
```

And this:

```
ng-repeat="year in [{{currentYear}} .. {{leastSearchYear}}]"
```

But it all ultimately generates to this:

```
<option value="? string: ?"></option>
```

I'm also getting an ugly angular js syntax error on console.

I know I'm doing it wrong.
What is the correct way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: what is it exactly that you want to be as set as options? ```ng-repeat``` is used for iterating over an array, not a single value

Comment: That's good that you decided to stop after 4 attempts, because in theory one could come with many more *imaginary* ways that this could work. Why not go to [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#usage) to see how `ng-repeat` is actually supposed to work?

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what are those 2 dots for in your ng-repeat, you don't need to use curly braces on an ng-repeat, and the ng-repeat doesn't work on selects, instead use ng-options, refer to documentation to see how to use it ;)